# Changing blockchain storage location in official wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, keystore, datadir

I'm aware that geth can take an option to change the location, as described here:
[Possible to store the blockchain in a different directory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/possible-to-store-the-blockchain-in-a-different-directory)

But what about the graphical Ethereum Wallet? There doesn't seem to be a config file anywhere. (I'm on Linux.)

My home directory is a flash drive and I have a larger disk drive for bulk storage, so changing would be nice.

If there's also a way to change the place keys are stored, that'd be cool too, since secure delete works better on disks than on flash.

Comment: Upvoted and I think the 2 "duplicates" provided covers this question.

Comment: It does, for some reason the Mist question didn't show up when I searched.

Comment: Now that I've tried it...the accepted solution was to run Mist with the datadir option, then run ethereum-wallet and it'll automatically connect to the running geth. That didn't actually work; instead ethereum-wallet complained it couldn't start geth because another geth was already running.