# How to persist data (the chain itself) in a Docker private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, docker

I'm creating a Docker private blockcain from here:

https://medium.com/scb-digital/running-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-using-docker-589c8e6a4fe8

But I'm afraid to lost all my data if I need to delete/deploy the container again.

Is there any way to create an external volume to save the chain data?

Comment: Sorry guys... I think I've found the answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/possible-to-store-the-blockchain-in-a-different-directory ... so I need to create a volume pointing to <DATA_DIR>/geth/

Comment: Not too fast!!  <DATA_DIR>/geth/ is already filled with the genesis data and if I mount a volume there it will be overriden. I think this is more like a Docker question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far:

Create a volume:

`docker volume create masternode_data`

Assign it to the node:

```
docker run --name=bc-masternode --hostname=bc-masternode \
--network=internal \
-p 30303:30303 \
-v masternode_data:/datadir \
...
```

Check the content:

```
docker run --rm -it -v masternode_data:/datadir busybox /bin/sh
```

Just keep in mind that this is a shared data. Don't mess anything...